# Can you extract/bring across the rating of a video from youtube to use in your own site?

Tags: html, api, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to extract the ratings (i.e. 5 stars), views and comments of a Youtube video and use it within your own site?

In other words I have a youtube video embeded on my site but i want to include the rating, views and comments of the video. Then use that information to display below video on my own website?

Hope that makes sense!

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go Ryano

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Ratings